# How to run test cases in parallel with appium and testNg?

Tags: appium

**Short question:**

I get following error when running my code in parallel in appium

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: A session is either terminated or not started
```

**Describe more**

I have a problem in running my test case in parallel, I have three config to run my test cases, first of all i can choose serial, when I choose serial i config my configuration file like the following style:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="base.TestListener"/>
        <listener class-name="base.AnnotationTransformer"/>
    </listeners>
    <test name="SM-A205F (R58M88N348V)">
        <parameter name="platformVersion" value="30"/>
        <parameter name="platform" value="ANDROID"/>
        <parameter name="config" value="..../configurations/1.json"/>
        <parameter name="appVersion" value="231218010"/>
        <classes>
            <class name="profile.testcase.NoteTestCase"/>
            …
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="SM-G960F (1cc4ce7e15037ece)">
        <parameter name="platformVersion" value="29"/>
        <parameter name="platform" value="ANDROID"/>
        <parameter name="config" value="..../configurations/2.json"/>
        <parameter name="appVersion" value="231218010"/>
        <classes>
            <class name="profile.testcase.ProfileTestCase"/>
            …
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

This will run my testCases in serial steps, first run in first device after all test case then run in second device and it works like a charm

Second config is parallel that I specify threadCount in suit tag like follow:

```
<suite name="Suite" parallel="tests" thread-count="2">
```

and pull all testCase class in two `test` tag. this state will run all test case in my two device and it works like a charm too.

**So whats is the problem?**

My third option is Spread, I want to combine this two option with separate test case between `test` tag and specify `threadCount` to make it parallel, but i've got following error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: A session is either terminated or not started
Build info: version: '4.16.1', revision: '9b4c83354e'
System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.2.0-26-generic', java.version: '17.0.8'
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver
```

I try many solution like specify different port hub and changing `parallel` value to `classes` or other value but i can't fix this issue. I read all related question in SO but i can't fix my problem.

PS:

This is config file that exists in test parameters, I have two file like this:

```
{
   "capabilities":[
      {
         "app":"..../nightly.apk",
         "browserName":"Android",
         "maxInstances":1,
         "udid":"1cc4ce7e15037ece",
         "deviceName":"SM-G960F",
         "version":"10",
         "platform":"Android"
      }
   ],
   "configuration":{
      "uiAnimatorPort":"8301",
      "hubHost":"127.0.1.1",
      "session-override":true,
      "hubPort":4446,
      "url":"http://127.0.1.1:4723/wd/hub",
      "nodePolling":2000,
      "timeout":20000,
      "platform":"ANDROID",
      "proxy":"org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy",
      "cleanUpCycle":2000,
      "port":"4723",
      "host":"127.0.1.1",
      "maxSession":1,
      "registerCycle":1000,
      "register":true
   },
}
```

and i change `udid`, `uiAnimatorPort`, `port` and `url` value for each config.